# To prove an identity in permutation and combination.

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am trying to prove the following identity:

${n \choose 0}$ + ${n \choose 1}$ + $\ldots$ + $\frac{1}{2}{n \choose n/2}$ = $2^{n-1}$ where $n$ is even

I know that I have to use few relations like ${n \choose r}$= ${n \choose {n-r}}$ AND ${n \choose 0}$ + ${n \choose 1}$ + $\ldots$ + ${n \choose n}$ = $2^n$ but no idea from where to start.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, and you know that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}=2^n$

Comment: @MichaelGaluza that''s what I wrote in problem. but no idea how to use them to prove it. :)

Comment: you say $\ldots$ but suddenly have a coefficient of 1/2 on the last combination. Is there a pattern?

Comment: @Nitin edited my question, n is assumed to be even.

Comment: @mathscrazy, it's *really* enough for solution) See answer of Brian below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $n$ is supposed to be even here. The two relations that you mention are exactly the tools that you need.

HINT:

$$\begin{align*}
\binom40+\binom41+\binom42+\binom43+\binom44&=\binom40+\binom41+\binom42+\binom41+\binom40\\
&=2\left(\binom40+\binom41+\frac12\binom42\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's a lovely explanation Sir. Thanks a lot. :) Sir, I am sorry to say but i think second last term on the right hand side should be $4 \choose 1$.

Comment: @mathscrazy: You’re welcome – and you’re absolutely right about the typo in that second-last term.

Comment: Nice way to tackle the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n = 2k$, and multiply $2$ to both sides ( clearing denominator ) we have:
$LHS = 2\binom{2k}{0} + 2\binom{2k}{1}+\cdots + 2\binom{2k}{k-1} + \binom{2k}{k} = \binom{2k}{0}+ \binom{2k}{1}+\cdots + \binom{2k}{k} + \binom{2k}{k+1} + \binom{2k}{k+2} + \cdots + \binom{2k}{2k} = 2^{2k} = RHS$

Comment: that's an interesting approach for me. Thanks for the help :)